# Counting Number of Times a Function of a Class is Excuted

Tags: python, class

I would like to count how many times I execute a specific function `FUNCTION` in a class `CLASS.` I tried to do it by definig a global variable within the class `counting_function_execution` and increasing it every time the function is executed:

```
class CLASS:
    global counting_function_execution 
    counting_function_execution  = 0

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def FUNCTION(self):
        print("Hi " + self.name)
        print("This function was already excecuted ", counting_function_execution, " number of times.")
        counting_function_execution += 1
```

However, when I do it:

```
test = CLASS("Fred")
test.FUNCTION()
test.FUNCTION()
```

I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-dc8f3ae96700> in <module>()
      1 test = CLASS("Fred")
----> 2 test.say_hi()

<ipython-input-100-d0166079c633> in say_hi(self)
      8     def say_hi(self):
      9         print("Hi " + self.name)
---> 10         print("This function was already excecuted ", counting_function_execution, " number of times.")
     11         counting_function_execution += 1
     12 

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counting_function_execution' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Henry, you're getting some confusing answers here because it's not 100% clear what you want especially if you have multiple instances of the class. If you want ONE count for all variables, you need to reference the class variable from the instance like:

```
class CLASS:
    # static class counting_function_execution 
    counting_function_execution  = 0

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def FUNCTION(self):
        print("Hi " + self.name)
        print("This function was already excecuted ", self.counting_function_execution, " number of times.")
        self.__class__.counting_function_execution += 1

c = CLASS("mark")
c.FUNCTION()      # 0
c.FUNCTION()      # 1

d = CLASS("john")
d.FUNCTION()      # 2
d.FUNCTION()      # 3

print(CLASS.counting_function_execution) #4
```

This will print 0 - 3 and  at the end `CLASS.counting_function_execution` will equal 4.

If you instead use `self.counting_function_execution += 1` each instance will get its own count and `CLASS.counting_function_execution` will be zero at the end because you never actually increment it.

Either way you can avoid the `global` variable which is a bonus.

Comment: Very nice answer !  Thanks a lot ! Would you mind to explain me / or add to your answer what `self.__class__.counting_function_execution` means? What is the purpose of the "__class__" after "self" ? Sorry, if this is trivial to you. I am very new to classes in python. Thanks !

Comment: @henry `self.__class__.` is a nice way to reference the class object without hard-coding the class name. Probably doesn't matter here, but if you subclass `CLASS` the subclasses can declare their own static variables separately and the instances calling this method will reference the correct one.

Comment: Hmm...okay, I understand that  `__class__` is a replacement for the actual name of the class, here "CLASS", which is very convenient, indeed ! :) ... but, I don't understand why `self.counting_function_execution` will count how many times `FUNCTION` is executed for each instance, but `self.__class__.counting_function_execution` counts it globally for all instances ?

Comment: One way to think about it is when instances reference `self.__class__` they all reference the same object which has an attribute `counting_function_execution`. Any instance accessing that is seeing and manipulating the same object. `self` however is unique to each instance and each one gets and attribute `counting_function_execution`

Comment: I see. Thank you very much !! Might I ask you for your help regarding a similar question ? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736676/count-how-many-times-a-function-is-excuted-after-another-function-for-an-instanc

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that in the function `CLASS.FUNCTION`, you are not referencing the class variable `counting_function_execution`, but rather, another local variable with the same name.
That is why the error is 'referenced before assignment', because you reference that local variable before you initialize it.

To reference the right variable, you can either use `self.counting_function_execution` (the instance's variable), or `CLASS.counting_function_execution` (the class's static variable)

Comment: Please forgive me, but I am quite new to classes. So I replaced the `counting_function_execution` in the `FUNCTION` by `self.counting_function_execution` , but I get: `AttributeError: 'CLASS' object has no attribute 'counting_function_execution'`

Comment: True, that is because of the `global counting_function_execution' line, that makes this variable not a class variable, but rather a global variable. just erase that line, and you'll be good

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

`counting_function_execution` is a class variable. If you want to access it from an instance of the class, use `self.counting_function_execution`. If you'd like to access it from the class itself, use `x.counting_function_execution`, where `x` is the name of the class (`CLASS` in this case)

Both ways work for your example

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! By "instance of the class", you mean a function within the class, right ? Also, what do you mean by "access it from the class itself " ?

Comment: By instance of the class, I mean if you declare an object like `class1 = CLASS()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are counting the execution per class, you can define something outside the class:

```py
counting_function_execution = 0

def count_func(func):
    def decorator_count(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global counting_function_execution
        counting_function_execution += 1
        print(counting_function_execution)
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator_count


class CLASS:
    # global counting_function_execution 
    # counting_function_execution  = 0

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    @count_func
    def FUNCTION(self):
        print("Hi " + self.name)
        #print("This function was already excecuted ", self.counting_function_execution, " number of times.")
```

If you are counting the execution per instance, you just need to add `self` when referring to it, i.e. `self.counting_function_execution`.

```py
class CLASS:
    # global counting_function_execution 
    counting_function_execution  = 0

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def FUNCTION(self):
        print("Hi " + self.name)
        print("This function was already excecuted ", self.counting_function_execution, " number of times.")
        self.counting_function_execution += 1
```

Comment: If you make multiple instances of `CLASS` will you have one counter or multiples with this?

Comment: I didn't downvote. But, per my question, I don't think this code does what you think it does.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Sorry, I thought so, because you commented and there was a downvote. To answer your question: I just tested it... If you create multiple instances, the counter restarts from 0 for every instance. This is good for my case. Would be interesting to know how to avoid that, if necessary...